# Ubuntu GTX 760x 6GB only detecting 2gb

Tags: nvidia

I have a NVIDIA GTX-760 6GB (according to Windows 10 DxDiag) and Ubuntu 14.04.5 can only detect 2GBs with no other processes running. Beyond installing Ubuntu, the only other thing I have installed are NVIDIA drivers.

Is there a way to solve this?

[This is my output for nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlSgK.png)

[Updated NVIDIA - still same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYX2x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing latest driver? I have `NVIDIA-SMI 367.57` installed though I have 3GB it shows 3 GB for me.

Comment: Yes just tried that too!

[link](https://s4.postimg.org/gecf3dl3x/15050353_10209789767954821_1592769676_n.jpg)